# C++ linked list memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

Hi I ran my program through valgrind and this is the report

Heap Summary:
in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
total heap usag: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 8 bytes allocated
Leak Summary:
definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks

This is my program

```
int main() {    
NodeData nodedata1(1, 'a');
List list1;
list1.insert(&nodedata1);

   return 0;
}
//---my List class
class List {
public:
   List(); 
   bool insert(NodeData*);                     // insert one Node into list
   bool isEmpty() const; 
private:
   struct Node {              // the node in a linked list
      NodeData* data;         // pointer to actual data, operations in NodeData
      Node* next;
   };
   Node* head;                                 // pointer to first node in list
};
// my bool insert method
bool List::insert(NodeData* rightPtr) {  
   Node* newPtr = new Node;
   newPtr->data = rightPtr;    
   if (isEmpty() || *newPtr->data < *head->data) {
      newPtr->next = head;                           
      head = newPtr;
   }
   else {
      Node* current = head; 
      while (current->next !=NULL && *current->next->data < *newPtr->data) {
           current = current->next;
      }
      newPtr->next = current->next;
      current->next = newPtr;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: List doesn't have a destructor that `delete` these nodes

Comment: Unless this is an exercise or homework, you should really save yourself all this trouble and use `std::list` instead.

Comment: You should create a destructor for your List to destroy all your Nodes when the List is destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dynamically allocating a `Node` in the `insert` method and never deleting it:

```
Node* newPtr = new Node;
```

You need to keep track of these `Nodes` and delete them in the `List` destructor, or have some other arrangement to handle the memory (i.e. pass the ownership of the `Nodes` to something that is in charge of deleting them at the right moment).

Comment: not homework, i'm just trying to learn linked list and how destructor and memory leak work

Comment: @ThuanTrinh The `NodeData` in main will be automatically handled, but the `Node* newPtr = new Node` in `List::insert(NodeData* rightPtr)` will not.

Comment: @Thuan Trinh if you create an object via "new" you always have to delete it. If you create the item by just declaring it, it's allocated on the stack and the compiler takes care to call the destructor when it leaves scope. This behavior is heavily used with RAII objects (check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: The `Node` you create is made to point to your input `NodeData` pointer. But that isn't the issue. The issue is that when you create something with `new`, something, somewhere has to delete it.

Comment: thanks guys. I added a destructor to walk down the list and delete each node.

Answer (score 4):

Object created by declaring it will be destroyed before its scope ends. Object that created using *new* will not be destroyed unless you manually delete it. The following example demonstrates lifetime of object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Data {
    protected:
        char* name;
    public:
        Data(char* n) {
            name = n;
            cout << name <<  " is created." << endl;
        }

        ~Data() {
            cout << name <<  " is destroyed." << endl;
        }
};

void ScopeDemo() {
    Data obj1("Obj1");
    Data* obj2 = new Data("Obj2");
}

int main()
{
    ScopeDemo();
    return 0;
}
```

In modern operating system, memory used by application will be released when the application terminated.

---

In your example, you will need to manually delete when **List** object is destroyed (which is via object destructor) and when you remove node from your **List**.

```
List::~List() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node* toDelete = head;
        while(toDelete != NULL) {
            Node* next = toDelete->next;
            delete toDelete;
            toDelete = next;
        }
    }
}
```